# Do the junction boxes for the oven and cooktop whips need to be easily accessible or can they be hidden behind the oven?

Tags: electrical

Do the junction boxes for the oven and cooktop whips need to 
be easily accessible or can they be hidden behind the oven?

Comment: To be clear, you're not talking about a cord-and-plug attached  range. Is that correct?

Comment: The device being served by the junction box never makes the box inaccessible, otherwise you'd never be able to install a light fixture.

Comment: I'd like to suggest that since every oven or cooktop installation I've encountered has the junction box hidden by the device it serves that it's probably okay, but based on the, um, interesting grounding techniques I encountered this weekend while updating some electrical work, I'd have to say just because one has seen it done a particular way doesn't mean it's okay. In this case however, I think you're probably okay.

Answer (score 8):

As long as the oven can be pulled out, and you can access the junction boxes that way, you're fine.